Effects of Day/Night divide on airflow patterns on a binary planet
I'm currently working on a project with a binary planetary system (both planets are around .8 earth mass with some variation), and naturally, the planets are tidally locked to each other, leading to a slower day (in this case, a flexible ~3.4 earth days) and therefore weaker coriolis force. I have some idea of how the overall coriolis forces would have an effect on surface air currents, but I don't know if the temperature differential between the day and night sides would create its own air currents as well.
Basically, would the day/night boundary have any large scale effects on the climate, or is it moving too fast?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Asking more than one question is literally a reason to close posts (see close reason "Needs More Focus"). Also, that comment by the automated Community BOT indicates that the question is confusing enough to fail one or more of Stack Exchange's "good question" metrics. Questions should be clear, concise, specific, and narrowly focused on just one problem.

Got it; is the new question sufficiently narrower?
